# WebRTC JavaScript com servidor Java/PHP

Tags: javascript, php, java, webrtc

Alguém ai tem algum exemplo ou documentação, de como criar um client WebRTC (navegador), utilizando um servidor Java ou PHP para fazer o "handshake" entre ambos?

Não posso utilizar node.js, e a documentação que encontro, está obtendo algumas informações do servidor node, as quais são necessárias para iniciar a conexão P2P.

Comment: Você poderia especificar as informações do servidor node necessárias para iniciar a conexão que você mencionou?

Answer (score 2):

Felipe,

Sua dúvida é com relação ao "client" de WebRTC ou ao servidor que será responsável pelo signaling (troca de mensagens)?

Se for com relação servidor, existem vários projetos de WebSocket em PHP, como:

- [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/)
- [phpwebsocket](https://code.google.com/p/phpwebsocket/)

Nos pontos de conexão WebRTC (Client/Server) você irá utilizar o WebSocket para sinalizar e enviar as mensagens que negociam a conexão entre os pontos, após isso esses pontos irão se conectar diretamente uns aos outros (ou por intermédio de um servidor TURN).

No site [WebRTC](http://www.webrtc.org/) tem muito material e conteúdo para te ajudar com a tarefa.

PS.:
Só por curiosidade, poderia me explicar o motivo de não poder usar servidor node?

Comment: O motivo da não utilização de node, são por definições da própria empresa.